# How to align points and sub points in a textview?

Tags: android, textview

My aim is to get something like this:
aligned points image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tI2N.png
but currently I am only able to get !
This https://i.stack.imgur.com/trMCv.jpg

i.e.: in a single textview

Heading

```
 Point 1

 Point 2

 Point 3

       Sub point 1
       Sub point 2
```

And so on...

I tried adding spaces but if the line is longer than the width of the screen it then starts from the mowt left part

Eg:

```
 Heading

      Text--------------------------This is 

 Point 1

     Text-------this is point 2
```

Here pont 1 is longer than width so continued from extreme left and not just below of starting of point 1

As shown in the uploaded image

It is not  looking good,
And I have no idea where to begin with to achive that kind of alignment.

I think spannable text may be used.
But I dont know how to align it like that.

Will AlignmentSpan work?
If yes how to use it to achieve that alignment?

Any direction or example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely want to have an IndentedTextView or something along those lines that adds padding or margins to the side to get the proper formatting your looking for.

Comment: But it is a single text view . Just adding padding will do the same for all headings and their points below ,which i don't want

Comment: Right. Can you just break it up into multiple paragraphs? That's going to be the best way. Another user added how to do bullets but the indentation is still going to be a problem, especially if you want multiple. I would recommend if you have dynamic text you put it in a recyclerview and set a different indentation depending on the item

Answer (score 0):

create a textview for each paragraph and make sure you set the same layout margin on each textview. Create a text resource for each text, if you want to add bullet points do this:

```
<string name="text_with_bullet">\u2022 Text with a point</string>
```

Comment: The number of points are variable.Can i make text views at run time?

Comment: you can programatically create textviews if thats what you are asking

Comment: Ok got some idea ,I will see whether it works or not

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `String.format`, you can see [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more details.